# Count the number of items in Array in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, count

**I have big file almost 2GB and text also includes so many countries, sometimes twise and more. I should create script what will write to stdout all countries from the file and also will show how many times the country name was used. for example if there is germany five times in file code Should show us: Germany: 5 (something like that)**

```
const fs = require("fs");
readline = require("readline");
stream = require("stream");

const filename = process.argv[2];
const instream = fs.createReadStream(filename);
const outstream = new stream();
outstream.readable = true;
outstream.writable = true;

const rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: instream,
  output: outstream,
  terminal: false,
});
rl.on("line", function (line) {
  const [country] = line.split(",", 1);
  Str = country;
  var obj = new Object();

  for (var i = 0; i < Str.length; i++) {
    if (obj[Str] != null) {
      obj[Str] += 1;
    } else {
      obj[Str] = 1;
    }
  }
  console.log(obj);
});
```

**I wrote this but it shows the number of letters in word.
Thank you (link for download file is in comments)**

Here is a part of text:

> united
> states,2001,dinner-and-a-murder-mystery-games,retail,linkedin.com/company/dinner-and-a-murder-mystery-games,"",dinner
> and a murder mystery games,tennessee,1-10,dinnerandamurder.com
> netherlands,2013,jennifer-campbell,management
> consulting,linkedin.com/company/jennifer-campbell,houten,jennifer
> campbell,utrecht,1-10,jennifercampbell.com united
> states,"",imtec-corp,marketing and
> advertising,linkedin.com/company/imtec-corp,ardmore,imtec corp
> italy,1977,bo.ma-s.r.l.,research,linkedin.com/company/bo.ma-s.r.l.

Comment: What does the file look like? Kinda impossible to help identify the issue if there is no data to look at

Comment: You can download file from here: 
https://go.peopledatalabs.com/l/831693/2020-12-09/hwt5z

Comment: I understand you cannot paste the full 2GB of data in the question, but can you paste an excerpt of it? you know wich lines are meaninful, maybe choose 20 of them to show the problem

Comment: @malarres Above there is a link to download it but there is a part of text:
united states,2001,dinner-and-a-murder-mystery-games,retail,linkedin.com/company/dinner-and-a-murder-mystery-games,"",dinner and a murder mystery games,tennessee,1-10,dinnerandamurder.com
netherlands,2013,jennifer-campbell,management consulting,linkedin.com/company/jennifer-campbell,houten,jennifer campbell,utrecht,1-10,jennifercampbell.com    
united states,"",imtec-corp,marketing and advertising,linkedin.com/company/imtec-corp,ardmore,imtec corp
italy,1977,bo.ma-s.r.l.,research,linkedin.com/company/bo.ma-s.r.l.

Comment: Instead of querying a 2GB file (you want all countries, or count the number of occurrences, etc) this sounds like a job for a database. I guess it would be worth parsing the file to a database, and then you can query all you want. Querying a 2GB file doesn't seem like a very practical goal. On top of that, it's a CSV file, data is already organized. It's easy to parse to a database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is probably, that you have a variable "country" that contains the  country as string and then you store it to Str and do:

```
"for (var i = 0; i < Str.length; i++) {
```

this loops over every char in the stream.
Also you need to define the "obj" outside of the callback otherwise it gets recreated for every line.
Just try:

```
var obj = {};
rl.on("line", function (line) {
  const [country] = line.split(",", 1);

  if (obj[country]) {
    obj[country]++;
  } else {
    obj[country] = 1;
  }
  console.log(obj);
});
```